# iOS - change view (UICollectionViewCell) to disabled status

Tags: ios, uitableview, disabled-control

I have a UICollectionView and I want some of my cells to be disabled. That means I want the cell to look a bit greyer (to have a disabled feeling), and I want the user to not be able to click on the cell.

I know I can use the alpha parameter and set it to something like 0.7, but this gets disabled while moving the cells around, and also it doesn't look grey enough. So I'm looking for another option to do it.

For controlling the tapping on a cell, I know I can use `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` and check for the indexPath. But I was wondering if there's another option for disabling a cell, like there is for disabling a UIButton:  `myButton.enabled = NO`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always set `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO` for the `UICollectionViewCell` and any taps inside it will be ignored.

Your problem with the alpha sound like you need to do some more work in `prepareForReuse`, or implement `prepareForReuse` in your custom cell class if you have not already done so.

Comment: Thanks @Lev. My alpha problem is to find the right way to make the view look disabled. What I understood about `prepareForReuse` is that is determines the cell's properties in case of scrolling - that's a problem I didn't think about yet.